# Best practice to query data from two (or more) schemas in NoSQL database

Tags: mongodb, nosql

say I have the following two schemas (`URL`, `User`) in a NoSQL database:

```
URL(url_id (key), url_text, user_id, ...)
User(user_id (key), user_name, user_password, ...)
```

And I've created indexes on `user_name` in `User` and `user_id` in `URL`. Now I want to obtain `url_text` given a `user_name` and this is a **read-heavy** system.

I can think about two options:

1. I use the `aggregation` functionality in the database to join these two schemas.
2. I use a programming language to query the database twice to get the result (ex. call `User.find({user_name: some_name})` and store the result `user_id` as the input for `URL.find({user_id: some_id})`)

What would be the best practice? Or what trade-offs should I consider when making decisions?

Comment: They are almost the same, the only difference is that the second one will take longer, do latency. A better option will be to normalise the user_name field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is nosql, you can approach this problem by adding `user_name` in the `URL` collection.

But if your system is more complex than shown in the question, you can go for option 1(aggregate query) with normalised model as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/)

I don't prefer second option due to additional network latency.

Comment: Right, I think the network latency really matters in my use case. I may also need to run some tests to compare these two approaches.

Comment: Exactly. Mongodb itself suggests to try different schemas which suits each data and its use case.